# Should I include "that" or not in sentences like "I saw (that) you waited for the bus"?

Tags: ellipsis

> I saw you waited for the bus. *(wrong unless add that)*
>   I saw **that** you waited for the bus. *(correct)*
>
> I saw a house destroyed on the road.  *(wrong unless add that)*
>   I saw **that** a house destroyed on the road. *(correct)*

But most of us omit “that” am I right?

Comment: The complete answer will even fit in a comment... [*Complementizer "that" is optional EVERYWHERE - EXCEPT at the beginning of a sentence, where it's necessary to identify the clause as subordinate...  **That you forgot is no excuse***.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/252158/126)

Answer (score 0):

"I saw a house destroyed on the road" is acceptable, but probably doesn't mean what you think.

It mean that the house was on the road (odd, houses are normally next to the road!) and you saw the process of it being destroyed.  You can clarify this with "being destroyed":

> I saw a house being destroyed.
>
> I watched as the house was destroyed.

It is not possible to treat "waited" in the same way.  "I saw you being waited" does not mean anything, because "wait" doesn't have an object. "I saw you *waiting* for the bus" is fine, but not "waited".

It is possible that you wanted "destroyed" to describe "house". The adjective "ruined" would be better: "I saw a ruined house"