# Is "that" superfluous in "What happens is ..."?

Tags: word-usage

I searched for [what happened is he](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1855&bih=956&sxsrf=ALeKk018pjRld53GUMSMOdkGlvOVGQSqcw%3A1593247515388&ei=Gwf3Xp-aF7-Sr7wP1f2-6Aw&q=%22%20what%20happened%20is%20he%20%22&oq=%22%20what%20happened%20is%20he%20%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQoAE6BAgAEEdQ4bQNWOG0DWCqtQ1oAHAFeACAATmIATmSAQExmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjfk8bBzaHqAhU_yYsBHdW-D80Q4dUDCAw&uact=5) and found many example where "that" is omit.

So my question is, is "that" unnecessary when paired with "what happened is?"

Example sentence (with a small tense change):

> What happened was **(that)** I got into an argument with my co-workers,
> so I headed back home alone.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think [**that**] "relativizing **that**" is ALWAYS "optional" in such contexts. It certainly is in your example.

Comment: It's hard to search out similar (possibly, ***duplicate***) questions about this, because of that word "that" that gets treated as a "noise" word by most text search algorithms. But maybe if I include the word ***canonical*** in this comment, I'll keep finding it for years to come whenever I search for ***canonical post relativizer complementizer that optional required*** (or whatever subset of those keywords I can call to mind at the time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't do better than cite this from [a comment from John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/465151/is-the-that-optional-in-my-idea-was-that#comment1122697_465151) to a similar question asked on ELU (my capitals and other formatting)...

> Since "that" is a complementizer, introducing and identifying clauses is its primary function.
> **Complementizer "that" is optional EVERYWHERE**,

> **EXCEPT**
> at the beginning of a sentence, where it's necessary to identify the clause as subordinate...
> *That you forgot is no excuse*,
> but not
> *You forgot is no excuse.*

Note that the above example is a slightly "starchy" way of saying what would more often be expressed as *It's no excuse **that** you forgot* - where "that" is definitely "optional" even if that *particular* example doesn't work quite as well as, say, *It's a pity [**that**] I didn't think of this example earlier!*
.